# Why CSMA/CD is unfair?

Tags: networking, tcp

In the CSMA/CD Protocol, my packet may be delayed even if my packet was already transmitted than other packets.

Think of this way :

Assume that each packet has 2 second to send to destination.

```
A sended pkt when 0s
B sended pkt when 1s
Collision was detected when 2s. so backoff policy is applied both A and B and dealy time is 1s
A sended pkt when 3s
B sended pkt when 4s
Collision was detected when 5s. so backoff policy is applied both A and B and dealy time is 2s
A sended pkt when 6s
B sended pkt when 7s
Collision was detected when 8s. so backoff policy is applied both A and B and dealy time is 4s
C sended pt when 9s
C's pkt successfully sended to dest when 11s
```

WHAT HAPPEND!? A and B wanted to send packet and indeed did before C but, the host that send a packet successfully is C.

This is unfair circustance in terms of A and B.

In this senario, we can see altruistic protocol like TCP, which has congestion control.
The reason why UDP is more fast than TCP is that TCP has congestion control, that can decrease the transmission speed

1. Is CSMA/CD also altruistic protocol like TCP??
2. Is there a protocol that can give a preoccupation of link to the host that sended before others.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: CSMA/CD is extinct for all practical purposes. Ethernet is run in switched environments today, and it is nearly impossible to find a hub. Yes, 10Base-T and 100Base-TX hubs were once quite common, and half duplex was written into the 1000Base-T protocol (although no 1000Base-T hubs were ever produced), but networking has moved on, and ethernet now uses switches (the newer standards of 10GBase-T, 25GBase-T, and 40GBase-T do not allow half duplex, so no CSMA/CD).

Comment: "_The reason why UDP is more fast than TCP is that TCP has congestion control, that can decrease the transmission speed_" Actually, TCP can be much faster than UDP in cases where reliability is required. UDP is certainly faster at sending, but you _will_ lose packets in transit, and if you need all the packets to arrive, then UDP can be much slower than TCP because it is up to the application to request lost data.